# "ajax:complete" not firing on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, heroku

I'm using `featherlight` to pop up a form generated by an ajax call to my Rails server. The form submits data with `remote => true` and the server responds with json. In my javascript I have

```
$(document).on('ajax:complete', handleAjaxComplete)
```

When the form gets submitted I close the form's featherlight box and open a new one with a spinner and wait until `ajax:complete` fires.

The weird thing is that in my local dev environment it fires and I can handle the response. On heroku it doesn't (even though the json gets sent through with status 200 and looking good.

My only theory was that it was because I was closing the featherlight box but then it shouldn't work on my local machine either right? Why would I receive a response and yet not have `handleAjaxComplete` called - there are no errors in the console (in fact I even get an "XHR finished loading: POST <url>" log)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is discussed here https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/223

It boils down to the fact that my form is in a lightbox. The lightbox fades out when you submit the form. On my local machine webrick responded fast enough for the form to still trigger `ajax:complete` while it was fading out. On heroku, however, the form had been removed from the DOM by the time `$.ajax` received a response so nothing happened. I could have resolved this by using jquery's own:

```
$.ajaxComplete()
```

(Or binding to that event) but I ended up just leaving the form open with a modal spinner above it until there was a response from the server.